# Useing fs.createReadStream and fs.createWriteStream for multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to loop over multiple files with fs.createReadStream, and I cannot figure out how to read the second file.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const csv = require('csv-parse')
const parser = csv({
  ...
})

const files = process.argv.slice(2)

async function analyzeFiles () {
  for (const file of files) {
    const string = file
    console.log(`Analyzing ${file}.`)
    await runFile(file, string)
    console.log(`Analyzed ${file}.`)
  }
}

async function runFile (filepath, string) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const shimmedData = {}
    let fileName = ''

    fs.createReadStream(filepath)
      .pipe(parser)
      .on('data', (row) => {
        // ...
        fileName = 'something dynamic from row'
        shimmedData[index] = row // Or something similar, not sure this matters
      })
      .on('error', (e) => {
        console.log('BONK', e)
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        
        fs.writeFile(`${fileName}.json`, JSON.stringify(shimmedData), (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            reject(err)
          } else {
            console.log('File written successfully.')
            resolve()
          }
        })
      })
  })
}

analyzeFiles()
```

And then I run `node script.js file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt`

When I run this, only the first file will ever be saved. Looking into it with console logs, it looks like for the second file, `fs.createReadStream` is never called.

```bash
➜  shimeBirdData git:(main) ✗ node stackoverflowExample.js sampleData/sample.txt sampleData/sample2.txt
Analyzing sampleData/sample.txt.
File written successfully.
Analyzed sampleData/sample.txt.
Analyzing sampleData/sample2.txt.
```

is saved.

What am I missing?

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to pare it down to make this example easier to get. Good catch, but that's not the issue here - in my side I have `sortedcounts.join('\n')`, an Array I make out of the data in shimmedData, for that line. Apologies. Edited it to remove that problem.

Comment: Which of the many log outputs are you getting? Please do some debugging and share your results with us.

Comment: The `console.log('BONK', e)` error handler really should just be `reject(e)`

Comment: Fundamentally, if you're never moving on to the next file, it's because you never settle the promise. So you need to debug it to find out why there's a path that never called `reject` or `resolve`. (@Bergi pointed out one path above which may be it; perhaps the second file *is* being reached, but then the read/parse is failing.)

Comment: Does the `node` process hang, or does it terminate? Did you confirm that `files` has 3 entries?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've run the above code, and I've added my response above. Only `VT.json` was saved, not `MA.json`, which also should have been from the data.